# Telerik Report Viewer page number box take in alphabets instead of numbers only

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik reporting Q3 2012.
In report viewer where we can manually enter the page number, that page number box takes in alphabets where it should only take numbers.

How do I restrict the input to numbers only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talal, it looks like Q1 2013 version fixed this issue. I created a WinForms application and I am unable to type numbers into the page number box.